# Clustered Quartz trigger is paused by Camel on shutdown

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have following configuration in a quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=JobCluster

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.chargebackDataSource.jndiURL=jdbc/myDataSource

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
```

Spring configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="quartz2" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent">
    <property name="propertiesFile" value="quartz.properties"/>
</bean>

    <route>
        <from uri="quartz2://myTrigger?job.name=myJob&amp;job.durability=true&amp;stateful=true&amp;trigger.repeatInterval=60000&amp;trigger.repeatCount=-1"/>
        <to uri="bean:myBean?method=retrieve"/>
....
```

On application shut down the Quartz trigger state changed to PAUSED and after the next start never changed to WAITING again so never fired again.

Is it possible to configure quartz/camel somehow to resume trigger after the application restart?

- Camel version is 2.12.0.
- Spring version 3.2.4.RELEASE

Actually such behavior contradicts with theit statement at guideline:

> If you use Quartz in clustered mode, e.g. the JobStore is clustered. Then the Quartz2 component will not pause/remove triggers when a node is being stopped/shutdown. This allows the trigger to keep running on the other nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamic suspend/resume routes as the

```
org.apache.camel.impl.ThrottlingRoutePolicy
```

does then its advised to use `org.apache.camel.SuspendableService` as it allows for fine grained suspend and resume operations. And use the `org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper` to aid when invoking these operations as it support fallback for regular `org.apache.camel.Service instances`.

For more details please refer [RoutePolicy](https://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) and [Quartz Component](http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html)

Hope this migh help

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I would assume that Camel should have an option to resume quartz trigger after application restart, otherwise Camel-Quartz integration just has no sense, if it doesn't support restarting and you have to manually change trigger status in database to WAITING.